# CASE WHEN LEN (x) > i THEN LEFT (x, j) + y ELSE x END

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wonder if there is single function in SQL Server, or at least a form without conditional `CASE`, that can replace following functionality:

```
CASE WHEN LEN (character_expression) > result_length THEN LEFT (character_expression, resultWithoutPad_length) + padWith_expression ELSE character_expression END
```

So that

```
CREATE TABLE foo (bar VARCHAR (MAX));
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('123456'), ('1234567'), ('12345678'), ('123456789'), ('1234567890'), ('12345678901'), ('123456789012');
SELECT CASE WHEN LEN (bar) > 10 THEN LEFT (bar, 7) + '...' ELSE bar END FROM foo;
```

will return following result:

> ```
> (No column name)
> ----------------
> 123456
> 1234567
> 12345678
> 123456789
> 1234567890
> 1234567...
> 1234567...
> ```

I tried `STUFF (character_expression, start, length, replaceWith_expression)`, but I cannot find way to modify it to suit my requirement.

Comment: how does your solution not suit your requirement?

Comment: I don't see how a function could be much simpler than what you already have

Comment: It suits okay. I just don't like how it looks and wonder if there is another better-looking one.

Comment: What version of SQL are you on? In 2012 you can use the IIF function.

Comment: Of course, there is not such function in T-SQL, but you can create user defined scalar function with this code.

Comment: Actually, I have a long `character_expression` involving `FOR XML` and complex query. Using my current solution, I'll have to repeat `character_expression` 3 times thus reduce readability. I have 2 options I can think of to shorten everything: [1] using a local variable to hold `character_expression` or [2] find a function or a shorter form that will do it all at once. I think I'll just use local variable and create a scalar UDF since I need this functionality often. `IIF` definitely good-looking, but I have to keep compatibility to SQL Server 2008 R2.

Comment: If your only remaining problem is that your function isn't good-looking enough, go home and have a beer, your job is done. Seriously, aren't there more important problems to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you ought to do in the presentation layer, not at the database level. If you want to have nice SQL, select the fields you want display and add an ellipsis in the HTML or whatever your application is.

If you must do it at the database level, you can write a UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION ellipsis(@str VARCHAR(MAX), @len INT) RETURNS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
  SET @str = CASE WHEN LEN(@str) > @len THEN LEFT(@str, @len - 1) + '…' ELSE @str END
  RETURN @str
END;

GO

CREATE TABLE foo (bar VARCHAR (MAX));
```

and

```
INSERT INTO foo (bar) VALUES ('123456'), ('1234567'), ('12345678'), ('123456789'), ('1234567890'), ('12345678901'), ('123456789012');

SELECT dbo.ellipsis(bar, 7) FROM foo;
```

result:

```
123456
1234567
123456…
123456…
123456…
123456…
123456…
```